# Problema al contar registros asociados a un registro de una tabla

Tags: mysql

Estimados estoy haciendo una consulta sql que me debe mostrar los vuelos y al lado la cantidad de reservas por vuelo, pero la consulta me suma todos los registros asociados y los asocia a un solo registro.

explico ejemplo de como debería mostrarse.

EJEMPLO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá un ejemplo del esquema de la bd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí esta la consulta sql

```
select v.lnar_cod_lnar,v.numero_vlos,v.fech_vlos,v.tpo_trans_vlos,count(r.cod_seq_rvas)as cantidad
from vlos v, trms t,rvas r,tvas tv

where v.seq_vlos=t.vlos_seq_vlos

and r.cod_seq_rvas=tv.rvas_cod_seq_rvas

and v.seq_vlos=tv.vlos_seq_vlos

group by v.lnar_cod_lnar;
```

Con la consulta sql yo intento mostrar todos los vuelos y al lado de cada registro mostrar la cantidad de reservas por vuelo

el problema es que me cuenta todo en la primera fila , me cuenta las reservas de varios vuelos y me las muestra en un solo vuelo como si todas esas reservas fueran de ese vuelo.

espero me puedan ayudar.
gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Falta más detalle en la estructura de las tablas involucradas en la consulta, para saber por qué campo te falta agrupar (que seguramente es el error)

Comment: Faltan campos en el group by. Te sugiero que revises en un manual cualquiera de sql **que no sea de mysql** como se hace una agrupacion. Desgraciadamente versiones anteriores de mysql permitian hacer trampa en los group by, y por eso te pasan estas cosas.

Comment: Si eso era ahora ya puedo ver lo que necesitaba

Comment: gracias solo debía agregar los otros campos en el group by